# Add Popup Modal on <a> link to open when User click on User column

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

Ok, so I have `Index Page` where it's is listed all ticket and I have column `User`.
I add `<a>` tag in this column

```
{
            "data": "applicationUser.name",
            "width": "10%",
            "targets": [1],
            "render": function (data) {
                return '<a class="text-info" href="' + data + '" target_blank>' + data + '</a>'
            }
        },
```

And also I create function to popup Modal

```
$(".table-info").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("userDetails");
    $.get("/Manager/Ticket/UserDetails?id=" + id, function (result) {
        $("#container").append(result);
        $("#userDetails").modal({ show: true })
    })
})
```

And here is `Modal Popup` which I create `PartialView.cshtml`

```
@model VmSTicketing.Models.ViewModels.TicketVM

<div class="modal fade" id="userDetails">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Podaci o Useru</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Ime i Prezime</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Ticket.ApplicationUser.Name" disabled id="ImePrezime" name="ImePrezime">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Email Adresa</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Ticket.ApplicationUser.Email" disabled id="Email" name="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Broj Telefona</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="Ticket.ApplicationUser.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" disabled id="BrTel" name="BrTel">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Klijent</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="Ticket.ApplicationUser.Client" class="form-control" disabled id="klijent" name="klijent">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is IndexPage for my table structure:

```
@model IEnumerable<VmSTicketing.Models.Ticket>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AdminLTE/_Layout.cshtml";

}


<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="text-primary">Lista tiketa</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Upsert"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Novi tiket</a>
    </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="p-4 border rounded">
    <table id="tblData" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr class="table-info">
                <th>Opis</th>
                <th>Datum i vrijeme slanja</th>
                <th>Vrsta Tiketa</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Datum i vrijeme zavrsetka</th>
                <th>Korisnik</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<partial name="UserDetails" />


@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/js/ticket.js"></script>
}
```

So far this modal work but when I click in `table header` not in User link.
I try to figure out what I make wrong but unfortunately I can not see where the error is.
So I want to add this function for popup to be load when User click on `<a>` tag
And here is my code `ticket.js` where I call my datatable

```
function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Manager/Ticket/GetAll"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "description", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "dateAndTime", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "ticketType.name", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "status", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "answered", "width": "15%" },
            {
                "data": "applicationUser.name",
                "width": "10%",
                "targets": [1],
                "render": function (data) {
                    return '<a class="text-info" href="' + data + '" target_blank>' + data + '</a>'
                }
            },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a href="/Manager/Discussion/OpenDiscussion/${data}" class="btn btn-primary text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="/Manager/Ticket/Details/${data}" class="btn btn-success text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-info"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a onclick=Delete("/Manager/Ticket/Delete/${data}") class="btn btn-danger text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> 
                                </a>                              
                            </div>
                           `;
                }, "width": "15%"
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

I am not sure how to assign this function to be load on  tag ??
Any suggestion ??

Comment: Not very clear what it is you need here. Are you wanting same event listener for `<a class="text-info">`?

Comment: Yes, I have everything prepare and liste in my post but I have no idea how to call this function to call on <a> link

Comment: Realated: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) also [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to adjust your `render` function `applicationUser.username` property in datatable js.

You can add a class for `user-details` :

```
"data": "applicationUser.name",
"render": function (data) {
   return '<a id="' + data + '" class="text-info user-details" href="' + data + '" target_blank>' + data + '</a>'
            }
```

and your event listener should go like following so that it should only be triggered when a data row is clicked but no the table header row :

```
$(".table-info").click("click" , "a.user-details",function () {
    var id = this.id;
    $.get("/Manager/Ticket/UserDetails?id=" + id, function (result) {
        $("#container").append(result);
        $("#userDetails").modal({ show: true })
    });
});
```

Currently your event triggers on the class `table-info` which is also applied on the `<tr>` for the `<th>` which is ending up not the behavior which is needed.

Comment: Doesn't work ! It display 
`This localhost page can’t be found`

Comment: @UnKnowUser this is how it will go, you further need to see what's the url being generated for hyperlink to fix it

Comment: Thank you :) Not it's better. Now, I am going to debug and see where is another mistake

Comment: @UnKnowUser also need to add ``id="'+data+'"`` in the `<a>` which is in `render` function, i have updated the code in answer for render function, hope it fixes the problem

Comment: Thank you so much ! Unfortunettly, location is not find. And I try to find where is the problem. Most probably in my controller and redirect

Comment: I get error message in console 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'guid' on string 'a.userDetails' `